# Segment fault with com.fasterxml.jackson.core.sym.ByteQuadsCanonicalizer.calcHash

Tags: java, jackson, couchdb, fasterxml, ektorp

I am using Ektorp 1.5.0 framework and Jackson 2.11.3 to serialize couchdb documents to/from JSON in a Spring 5 web application running on Tomcat 8 and Ubuntu 14. Occasionally I get a segment fault that produces a file hs_err_pid19743.log. There isn't anything particular about the documents being serialized and it works most of the time.

Is there a way to turn off the ByteQuadsCanonicalizer or anyone know how to fix this?

```
Current thread (0x00007f8ddcbb7800):  JavaThread "http-nio-8080-exec-7" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=19931, stack(0x00007f8cf0cd7000,0x00007f8cf0dd8000)]

Stack: [0x00007f8cf0cd7000,0x00007f8cf0dd8000],  sp=0x00007f8cf0dd1720,  free space=1001k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
J 36324 c2 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.sym.ByteQuadsCanonicalizer.calcHash([II)I (115 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dccfcda37 [0x00007f8dccfcd920+0x0000000000000117]
J 20364 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.sym.ByteQuadsCanonicalizer.findName([II)Ljava/lang/String; (218 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc6650454 [0x00007f8dc6650300+0x0000000000000154]
J 19972 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.findName([IIII)Ljava/lang/String; (58 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc65367e4 [0x00007f8dc65362c0+0x0000000000000524]
J 19971 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseLongName(III)Ljava/lang/String; (381 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc653561c [0x00007f8dc6534d60+0x00000000000008bc]
J 19349 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseMediumName2(II)Ljava/lang/String; (283 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc6373444 [0x00007f8dc6372fc0+0x0000000000000484]
J 20917 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.parseMediumName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (269 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc4641e8c [0x00007f8dc4641a40+0x000000000000044c]
J 18023 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parseName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (312 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc584aeec [0x00007f8dc584a6e0+0x000000000000080c]
J 30024 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextFieldName()Ljava/lang/String; (493 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc65afb7c [0x00007f8dc65aeb80+0x0000000000000ffc]
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;Ljava/util/Map;)V+63
J 35108 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;)Ljava/util/Map; (252 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc749df3c [0x00007f8dc749c3c0+0x0000000000001b7c]
J 35107 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (7 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc6cca3c4 [0x00007f8dc6cca340+0x0000000000000084]
J 22983 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V (127 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc6a301ac [0x00007f8dc6a2fe40+0x000000000000036c]
J 21586 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonToken;)Ljava/lang/Object; (102 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc60c1fbc [0x00007f8dc60c1a80+0x000000000000053c]
J 21585 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (62 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc6010adc [0x00007f8dc6010560+0x000000000000057c]
J 22108 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Ljava/lang/Object; (228 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc67f7564 [0x00007f8dc67f6a00+0x0000000000000b64]
J 23102 c1 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (28 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc6a9283c [0x00007f8dc6a91800+0x000000000000103c]
j  org.ektorp.impl.StdCouchDbConnector$5.success(Lorg/ektorp/http/HttpResponse;)Ljava/lang/Object;+17
J 22075 c1 org.ektorp.http.RestTemplate.handleResponse(Lorg/ektorp/http/ResponseCallback;Lorg/ektorp/http/HttpResponse;)Ljava/lang/Object; (52 bytes) @ 0x00007f8dc67e8964 [0x00007f8dc67e86c0+0x00000000000002a4]
j  org.ektorp.http.RestTemplate.get(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/ektorp/http/ResponseCallback;)Ljava/lang/Object;+14
j  org.ektorp.impl.StdCouchDbConnector.get(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/ektorp/Options;)Ljava/lang/Object;+46
j  org.ektorp.impl.StdCouchDbConnector.get(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  org.ektorp.support.CouchDbRepositorySupport.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;+9
```